# Hibernate HQL Count Distinct not working?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, hql

I have the following classes:

```
class User {
  hasMany = [ratings: Rating] 
} 

class Item {
 hasMany = [ratings: Rating]
}

class Rating {
 belongsTo = [user: User, item: Item]
}
```

I want to count the distinct users that rated on an item.

The following does not work:

```
select count(distinct(r.user)) from Rating as r
        where r.item=:item
        group by r.user
```

**How do I have to modify the HQL query to make it work?**

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your query should work as expected with a minor modification to the way you use `distinct`:

```
select count(distinct r.user) from Rating as r 
where r.item = :item group by r.user
```

An other, but more lengthy way, of doing this query is by using `User` and `join`:

```
select count(distinct u) from User as u 
inner join u.ratings as r where r.item = :item
group by r.user
```

Comment: It's really strange that the extra parens inside of the count on the distinct cause it to fail with a syntax error. This is the correct fix. Certainly saved me tons of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do in Hibernate Criteria

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Rating.class)
.add(Restrictions.like("item", item)
.addOrder(Order.asc("user"))
.setProjection(
       Projections.distinct(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("user"), "user")))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Rating.class));
```

Comment: How can I do that with HQL?

Comment: select distinct r.user from Rating r where r.item=:item group by r.user;
Then do a size()?

Comment: is there a way to do it in one query?

Comment: It's inneficient doing it that way, since you will be listing *every* record just to see how many of them are present. For a better example using criteria, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164717/hibernate-criteria-for-finding-count-for-distinct-value

Comment: Note that the criteria API has a Projections.countDistinct(). If you use that it will give the correct behavior with a lot less code. I think you can use crit.setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("user"));

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct as keyword not function, inside count function like-

```
count(distinct column) : Works

count(distinct(column)): Doesn't work
```