# Hibernate criteria for finding count for distinct value

Tags: hibernate

I have the following sql query ,i need to get the corresponding hibernate criteria query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) FROM erp_hr_payment WHERE payment_id IN(
SELECT payment_id FROM erp_hr_payment_collection WHERE payment_id IN(
SELECT payment_id FROM erp_hr_payment_collection WHERE payment_id IN(
SELECT payment_id FROM erp_hr_payment
 WHERE for_month BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2014-03-31' AND arrear_flag=0
) AND element_name='EPF' ) AND element_name='EPFV');
```

Comment: funny query that is ...

Answer (score 8):

Begin from most inner query create relative `DetachedCriteria` and attach to outer query using `Subqueries.in()`.
For `count(distinct)` use `Projections.countDistinct(propertyName)`.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

- Create detached criteria.  one for each of the inner queries.
- Put detached criteria in the "in" clause for the main criteria
- Use countDistinct projection to get distinct count of employees

  ```
  DetachedCriteria erp_hr_paymentDetachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Erp_hr_payment.class,"erp_hr_payment");
  erp_hr_paymentDetachedCriteria.setProjection(Property.forName("payment_id"));

  Criteria erp_hr_paymentMainCriteria = session.createCriteria(erp_hr_payment.class, "pogHeader");
  erp_hr_paymentMainCriteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.alias(Projections.countDistinct("erp_hr_payment.employee_id"), "distinctEmployeeCount")));
  erp_hr_paymentMainCriteria.add(Property.forName("erp_hr_payment.payment_id").in(erp_hr_paymentDetachedCriteria));
  erp_hr_paymentDetachedCriteria.list(); //Will give you your result
  ```

Comment: I'm not able to use your snippet, because DetachedCriteria isn't providing the method `list()` - also see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/DetachedCriteria.html